# Using NVIDIA Optimus on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

I have a laptop with a GeForce 940MX which I would like to use. Unfortunately installing the official nvidia drivers under "additional drivers" and reverting from wayland to x11 does not do the trick.
If I try to use prime-select nvidia, then under "settings" the graphics option becomes "unknown".

Should I use bumblebee? Is there anyone that successfully activated nvidia settings on ubuntu 17.10?

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to the title.That is not how askubuntu works: accept your own answer and the system will mark this question as solved.

Comment: Apparently askubuntu works by not letting me accept my answer until tomorrow for some reason. I just wished to help people looking for answers and avoid, as it happened to me, to wander into dozens of unanswered questions on dozen of websites. But I guess they'll have to wait 24 hours since that's how askubuntu works...

Comment: That's to avoid abuse unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that when the NVIDIA installers ask "do you want me to disable secure boot?" and lets you input a password it does it just for a show. It never ACTUALLY disables secure boot. By entering the BIOS, disabling it manually, and rebooting the GPU automagically appears!

Ah, of course this just works only under x11, not under the damned Wayland environment. So first revert to x11, then disable secure boot, then work on NVIDIA.

I have some comments about this, but I think I can be banned for obscenity on this website, so I'll keep my mouth shut.